# DataSnapshot in Firebase - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I am developing a simple chat application and i followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/IHHLyeak46E to create this chat. But i am facing a problem  with my dataSnapshot. I have deployed the app on 2 phones. But what happens is, when the Datasnapshot detects changes in the database, it doesn't update my listview with **only** my recent chat but together with previous messages already in the chat and i end up having duplicated messages. In the tutorial, it worked fine.  I don't really know if it is because of the foreach loop.  Why is this happening?

```
public  void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {


                var items = snapshot.Child("key")?.Child("users id")?.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();

                HashMap map;
                foreach(DataSnapshot  item in items){

                map = (HashMap)item.Value;
                    allMessages.Add(new EventMessageContent(map.Get("username")?.ToString(), map.Get("content")?.ToString()));
                }

                CommentViewAdapter adapter = new CommentViewAdapter(this, allMessages);
                allMessages.Adapter = adapter;

              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to clear your list on every update.

```
public  void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                allMessages.clear();

                var items = snapshot.Child("key")?.Child("users id")?.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();

                HashMap map;
                foreach(DataSnapshot  item in items){

                map = (HashMap)item.Value;
                    allMessages.Add(new EventMessageContent(map.Get("username")?.ToString(), map.Get("content")?.ToString()));
                }

                CommentViewAdapter adapter = new CommentViewAdapter(this, allMessages);
                allMessages.Adapter = adapter;

              }
```